# Replacing backtick in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
my_places = ['Bernardo O\'Higgins', 'Bernardo O`Higgins', 'Bernardo O\"Higgins'] 
adf = pd.DataFrame({'my_places':my_places})
adf
    my_places
0   Bernardo O'Higgins
1   Bernardo O`Higgins
2   Bernardo O"Higgins
```

And I try to replace the characters ',` and " with ''. So I tried this:

```
adf['my_places_check'] = adf['my_places'].replace(''|"|`','')
```

But I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I think I have to 'escape' the special characters, so I tried this:

```
adf['my_places_check'] = adf['my_places'].replace('\'|\"|\`','')
```

But it returns this:

```
    my_places   my_places_check
0   Bernardo O'Higgins  Bernardo O'Higgins
1   Bernardo O`Higgins  Bernardo O`Higgins
2   Bernardo O"Higgins  Bernardo O"Higgins
```

And I expected:

```
    my_places   my_places_check
0   Bernardo O'Higgins  Bernardo OHiggins
1   Bernardo O`Higgins  Bernardo OHiggins
2   Bernardo O"Higgins  Bernardo OHiggins
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```py
adf['my_places_check'] = adf['my_places'].replace("""["`']""", '', regex=True)
```

*Details*:

- `` """["`']""" `` - a regex that is `` ["`'] ``
- `''` - is the replacement (an empty string)
- `regex=True` - make sure the pattern is parsed as a regex

If you use `"` or `'` as a string literal delimiter, you will need to escape the corresponding literal char inside the string literal, so using a triple-quoted string literal is a more readable solution.

Comment: Hello @Wiktor Stribiżew, I was about to ask about the triple `"`, I thought that for regex I needed to begin with 'r'. Thank you very much for your time and kind explanation.

Comment: @Alexis The `'''....'''` or `"""...."""` triple-quoted string literals are used to avoid escaping single `'` or `"` chars. Raw string literals are used to avoid escaping backslashes (but then you cannot use string escape sequences, which is mitigated by identical regex escape sequences in most cases).

Comment: I appreciate your time on explaining the triple-quote string literal @Wiktor Stribiżew, hope you have a great great day and again, thank you.